# Probability Urn

Tags: probability, solution-verification

> Suppose that an urn has 1 green ball, 1 yellow ball, 1 blue ball and 1 red ball. You draw 4 with replacement. What is the probability that you draw exactly two are exactly the same color?

So I know that the sample space is $4^4$, but I thought that the possible out comes would be $4$ for the first pick, $4$ for the second pick, then $3$ for the third pick, and two for the last draw. Am I on the right track?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The result must contain 2 of one colour and 1 each of two other colours, one colour must be absent.

There are 4 ways to select the colour that will appear twice

There will then be 3 ways to select the two other colours.

for each colour combination there will be $$\frac {4!}{2!}=12$$ arrangements.

So it total there will be $(4)(3)(12)=144$ arrangements with exactly one colour appearing twice.

Answer (score 0):

The sample space for this event is correct. It is very easy to think about this in a visual sense. The only way that this event would happen is if you draw two green balls, two yellow balls, two red balls, and two blue balls with replacement.

So, I believe you are on the right track. A better way to check is to do a tree diagram.